# Intercambio de datos en SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-11g

¿Alguien sabe como intercambiar los datos entre una fila (registro) y otra en SQL? Para ser clara pongo un pequeño ejemplo: el estudiante con el id=8 intercambia todos sus datos (nombre, apellido, etc) con el estudiante de id=22, cada id queda con sus nuevos datos.

Comment: Investiga sobre cursores implícitos y explícitos

Comment: si tenes que hacer eso, hay algo mal en tus datos, porque el id no deberia importar nunca.. Igual, no es algo que tengas que hacer con sql, si no con un programita (aunque sea un pl) y alguna tabla temporal...

Comment: vale, muchas gracias, entonces voy a investigar un poco

Comment: Si las restricciones te lo dejan hacer, Intercambia los ID, va a ser más simple que intercambiar los datos.